# How do I calculate the running time of insertion sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose that you run the code fragment below (generate and then insertion-sort an array of numbers) for n=10,000 and observe that it takes 5.3 seconds. Which of the following is a reasonable prediction of its running time (in seconds) for n=1,000,000?

insertionsort([i for i in range(n)])

Comment: Hi, your question looks like an homework. What have you tried since now to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

We know (If you don't know yet - read algorithmic books immediately) that the worst and average time for insertion sort is quadratic, i.e. execution time depends on input length as `O(n^2)` (squared `n`).

For rather large `n` values we can write

```
T = k * n^2
```

and find constant `k` from given `n` (10000 in your case) and time T (5.3 seconds).

Then use the same equation with calculated `k` constant and another `n` value (1,000,000) to get estimated time.

---

Small remark: there is possibility that your code (unseen) does generate almost sorted array. In this case there are nuances....